# Как вызвать функцию для всех элементов объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var accordionsMenu = $('.cd-accordion-menu');

    if( accordionsMenu.length > 0 ) {

        accordionsMenu.each(function(){
            var accordion = $(this);
            //detect change in the input[type="checkbox"] value
            accordion.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
                var checkbox = $(this);
                console.log(checkbox.prop('checked'));
                ( checkbox.prop('checked') ) ? checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:none;').slideDown(300) : checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:block;').slideUp(300);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Можно ли сделать, чтобы блок:

```
accordion.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
                var checkbox = $(this);
                console.log(checkbox.prop('checked'));
                ( checkbox.prop('checked') ) ? checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:none;').slideDown(300) : checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:block;').slideUp(300);
            });
```

срабатывал не по событию `change`, а при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Можно. Нужно запустить эту функцию, после загрузки страницы. Событие называется `window.onload`

Comment: accordion.on('window.onload', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    var checkbox = $(this);
    console.log(checkbox.prop('checked'));
    ( checkbox.prop('checked') ) ? checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:none;').slideDown(300) : checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:block;').slideUp(300);
   }); так?

Comment: я в Jquery не силен. Я  только лишь догадываюсь, как работает Ваш код. Поэтому так или нет - сказать не могу. На чистом JS я бы написал так `window.onload = function(){ someFunction(){console.log("work")},  someFunction();    };`

Comment: @Abs3akt Если вы правите сообщение, то постарайтесь не делать это однобоко, а также править формат кода и правопиисание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может "не **только** по событию `change`, а **также** при загрузке страницы"?

Ни цикл, ни проверка `length` не нужны.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  //detect change in the input[type="checkbox"] value
  $('.cd-accordion-menu').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    var checkbox = $(this);
    console.log(checkbox.prop('checked'));
    ( checkbox.prop('checked') ) ? checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:none;').slideDown(300) : checkbox.siblings('ul').attr('style', 'display:block;').slideUp(300);
  });
  // при загрузке страницы:
  $('.cd-accordion-menu input[type="checkbox"]').change();
});
```

Comment: работает как надо, большое спасибо